# Postgresql Custom Sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to sort by a column where I want numbers to be ASC, but the last 2 rows should always be 0 then 1 (if they exists)

**For example:**

- 8
- 6
- 10
- 0
- 2
- 1

becomes

- 2
- 6
- 8
- 10
- 0
- 1

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the clearest is to order *both* by

```
CASE WHEN column_name = 0
     THEN 0
     WHEN column_name = 1
     THEN 1
     ELSE -1
 END
```

(which puts all values except `0` and `1` before `0`, and `0` before `1`) *and* by `column_name` (so that the non-`0`, non-`1` values appear in order).

For example:

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM table_name
 ORDER
    BY CASE WHEN column_name = 0
            THEN 0
            WHEN column_name = 1
            THEN 1
            ELSE -1
        END,
       column_name
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOURTABLE
ORDER BY CASE YOURCOLUMN
         WHEN YOURCOLUMN=0 THEN 0
         WHEN YOURCOLUMN=1 THEN 1
         ELSE -99
         END;
```